# Why can't I install a .deb file

Tags: debian

When I try to install `antimicrox-3.2.1-x86_64.deb` and confirming I want to install it I get an error saying:

`Failed to install file. A package could not be found that allows the action to complete. More information is available in the detailed report.`

I am relatively new to Debian and Linux as a whole so I don't know where to find the detailed report. Is there an explanation to this error?

Here is where I downloaded the file: https://github.com/AntiMicroX/antimicrox/releases

Comment: because raspberry pi isn't a x86_64 architecture - it's `armhf` architecture you're looking for - or `arm64` if you're running 64 bit raspberry pi OS - which I doubt

Comment: though, the deb package you want to install doesn't seem to come in `arm` flavour - you'll have to compile it from source

Comment: though - if you look at the github issues, you'll find lots of help https://github.com/AntiMicroX/antimicrox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+raspberry+is%3Aclosed+ and you can even use debian repository to install it without needing to compile - it's in one of those issues linked before - https://github.com/AntiMicroX/antimicrox/issues/121

Comment: not sure which thing worked - you could write an answer to your own question detailing exactly what you did :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was installing the wrong version. After taking a download from [this page](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/armhf/antimicro/download), it worked perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).